# Fancybox resize doesn't work

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I need to display image and one button on fancybox popup but I can't get it to display right.

I've tried it with two different methods:

1. Getting image and appending button to HTML.

   ```
   $('a.zoom').fancybox({
       type: 'image',
       onComplete: function() {
          $('#fancybox-content').append('<button>Click</button>');
          $.fancybox.resize() // this won't do anything
       }
   });
   ```

   This way, the popup box is height of the image and button is not visible.
2. Displaying HTML.

   ```
   $('a.zoom').live('click', function(ev) {
       ev.preventDefault();
       var url = $(this).attr('href');
       var content = '<img src="' + url + '" />';
       var id = $(this).parent().attr('data-frame-id');

       $.fancybox({
           content: content + '<button>Click</button>',
           type: 'html',
           onComplete: function() {
               $.fancybox.resize();
           }
       });
   });
   ```

   This way, popup boxes height is correct but width is only button width.

With both methods, `$.fancybox.resize()` doesn't seem to do anything and options `autoScale` and `autoDimensions` either.

How can I display both image and button correctly?

---

Generated HTML

```
<div id="fancybox-overlay" style="background-color: rgb(119, 119, 119); opacity: 0.7; cursor: pointer; height: 937px; display: block; "></div>
<div id="fancybox-wrap" style="width: 1020px; height: auto; top: 34px; left: 421px; display: block; ">
    <div id="fancybox-outer">
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-n"></div>
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-ne"></div>
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-e"></div>
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-se"></div>
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-s"></div>
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-sw"></div>
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-w"></div>
        <div class="fancybox-bg" id="fancybox-bg-nw"></div>
        <div id="fancybox-content" style="border-width: 10px; width: 1000px; height: 809px; ">
            <img id="fancybox-img" src="http://localhost/img.php?id=24" alt="">
            <button id="usethis">Use this frame</button>
        </div>
        <a id="fancybox-close" style="display: inline; "></a>
        <div id="fancybox-title" style="display: none; "></div>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="fancybox-left">
            <span class="fancy-ico" id="fancybox-left-ico"></span>
        </a>
        <a href="javascript:;" id="fancybox-right">
            <span class="fancy-ico" id="fancybox-right-ico"></span>
        </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: maybe a css-file that you're importing to the page is manipulating the button-layout. can you provide us with the genereated html-code?

Comment: the button to do what? you can do it also by iframe

Comment: @ClydeFrog Added generated HTML. And no, I don't have any style added to buttons. I think fancybox is getting height and width of the content it gets, i.e on `type: 'image'` it's image dimensions and on `type: 'html'`, it's the buttons height and width. I'm out of ideas on how do display it correctly. I've read that iframe's are bad habits and I've never worked with them.

Comment: maybe the button should be placed inside the `<div id="fancybox-title">`? since that the purpose of the `<div id="fancybox-content">` is only meant for the image

Comment: @ClydeFrog Yes! It worked! Thanks man, add this also as an answer

Comment: i'm glad that it's working for ya :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button should be placed inside the `<div id="fancybox-title">` since that the purpose of the `<div id="fancybox-content">` is only meant for the image